# Check if there is a translation available in PHP gettext

Tags: php

I am using PHP's gettext to translate a site that is being developed. Currently the translation is from en_AU to ar_SA which means the direction of the text needs to change from left-to-right to right-to-left.

The issue I have is that not all the site is ready to be translated so there will be some sections still in english. Is there a way to detect if there is an available translation and if so use rtl and if not use ltr?

Cheers

Comment: Why not just base your ar_SA translation on en_AU, then if you haven't translated a certain message, it will automatically be displayed in English.

Comment: `if ($str === gettext($str)) // probably no translation`...?